# amount of data and conv net performances

Tags: neural-networks, python, conv-neural-network

here the following problem.

I'm trying to do classification with conv net. I got a small amount of data (3000 images for 20 class). I do a 60/20/20 split (60% train, 20% validation,20% test set).

Performance are good but still not perfect.

I tryied to only use 1500 images. Performances decreased just a bit (less than 1% accuracy lost)

Based on those result:

- hypothesis 1: Can I says increasing data amount will not increase performances?
- hypothesis 2: I can only says using 2k data or 4k is equal, but I have no idea with, for example, 8k data

Answer (score 0):

You should compute the learning curve at many points and look at its trend. Say 10-20 points. Only change the amount of training data used. Use the same validation and test sets. 
If you have variation in your training process, compute the training metric multiple times per point (3-10x). Plot error bars together on the learning curve. Now you have a reasonable set of data to evaluate whether more data will increase your performance (on this model) significantly.
The expectation is that at some point there are diminishing returns, so the curve will be similar to a logarithm.

Comment: thanks. About **The expectation is that at some point there are diminishing returns, so the curve will be similar to a logarithm** what make you says we can expect this? theorical thing or because this is the pattern we see in a lot of model using conv net for classification?